# print updated label variable in main

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I want to read out the current value of the label variable, to send it to a 8x7-Segment display later on. For now I print it to check the value, I only get back 0 and not the current value.

```
from Tkinter import *

class CounterAway(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.countera = 0
        self.ca = StringVar()
        self._update_counter()

def _update_counter(self):
    self.ca.set(str(self.countera))

def count_up(self):
    self.countera += 1
    if self.countera > 99 : self.countera = 0
    self._update_counter()

def count_down(self):
    self.countera -= 1
    if self.countera < 0 : self.countera = 0
    self._update_counter()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()  
    """root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))"""
    root.geometry('1000x1000')  
    counteraway = CounterAway(root)


Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away +', command=counteraway.count_up).place(x=450, y=300)   
Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away -', command=counteraway.count_down).place(x=450, y=370)
Button(root, width=10, font=('Arial',30), text='Quit', command=root.destroy).place(x=10, y=10)
counteraway_label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", textvariable=counteraway.ca).pack()

print counteraway.ca.get()

root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I thought it will work with .get() but that seems to be wrong.

Comment: You are calling `get()` before `main()` or `mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

You’re executing `counteraway.ca.get()` before the `main()` function is executed, so the `counteraway` variable is not yet initialized. And because of that, `counteraway.ca.get()` won’t work.

If you put

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Before

```
Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away +', command=counteraway.count_up).place(x=450, y=300)   
Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away -', command=counteraway.count_down).place(x=450, y=370)
Button(root, width=10, font=('Arial',30), text='Quit', command=root.destroy).place(x=10, y=10)
counteraway_label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", textvariable=counteraway.ca).pack()

print counteraway.ca.get()

root.mainloop()
```

, it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful to make sure indentation is correct when posting python code.

The reason that 0 is printed is because that is the value of the variable when `print counteraway.ca.get()` is executed. If you printed the value inside a function that is called again when the value is updated by your buttons then it will print correctly.

For example if you change the `_update_counter` function to this:

```
def _update_counter(self):
    self.ca.set(str(self.countera))
    print self.ca.get()
```

You will see it print out the correct value each time you click the button to update the value.

With the indentation fixed the full code would be something like:

```
from Tkinter import *

class CounterAway(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.countera = 0
        self.ca = StringVar()
        self._update_counter()

    def _update_counter(self):
        self.ca.set(str(self.countera))
        print self.ca.get()

    def count_up(self):
        self.countera += 1
        if self.countera > 99 : self.countera = 0
        self._update_counter()

    def count_down(self):
        self.countera -= 1
        if self.countera < 0 : self.countera = 0
        self._update_counter()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()  
    """root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))"""
    root.geometry('1000x1000')  
    counteraway = CounterAway(root)


    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away +', command=counteraway.count_up).place(x=450, y=300)   
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away -', command=counteraway.count_down).place(x=450, y=370)
    Button(root, width=10, font=('Arial',30), text='Quit', command=root.destroy).place(x=10, y=10)
    counteraway_label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", textvariable=counteraway.ca).pack()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, this working, so I can see the updated value, but what if I want to have the current value in my main routine, is there a possibility to get this value?

Comment: ```root.mainloop()``` is essentially a loop that keeps going around until you close your Tkinter window so any code after this will not be executed until the window is closed so off the top of my head I can't think of a way to get this value without using multi-threading. The easiest way to use the value is to do it in the function give as the command (```command=```) I would have thought. Someone who has more experience with Tkinter may have a better solution though!